# Access 2013 Linking to SQL tables fails after conversion to ACCDB

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an old Access dB that is currently in 2000 - 2003 .MDB format. After converting to .ACCDB the following code fails to attach SQL server tables. When reattaching the SQL tables through code, I get the following error: **Object invalid or no longer set.** It fails on the **cat.Tables.Append tbl** line.
It works fine running the .MDB format dB in Access 2013, but after converting to 2007 format, it fails. I know I can leave it as an MDB file, but I want to convert up to avoid future problems. I have tried different connection string settings with no help.

Abbreviated Code:

```
Dim tbl As New ADOX.Table, cat As New ADOX.Catalog
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim ProviderString As String

Set cat.ActiveConnection = CurrentProject.Connection    
ProviderString = "ODBC;" & _
    "Provider=SQLOLEDB;" & _
    "Driver=SQL Server;" & _
    "Server=" & sServerName & ";" & _
    "database=" & sDatabaseName & ";" & _
    "UID=" & gbldbLogin & ";" & _
    "PWD=" & gbldbPassword

    TableName = "MyTableName"

    DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, TableName

    tbl.Name = TableName
    Set tbl.ParentCatalog = cat
    tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Link Provider String") = ProviderString
    tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Remote Table Name") = TableName
    tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Create Link") = True
    tbl.Properties("Jet OLEDB:Cache Link Name/Password") = True
    cat.Tables.Append tbl
    Set tbl = Nothing
```

Comment: That worked perfectly for me as it stands in Access 2013. Perhaps you could try with a new database?